# Inserting numbers from one array to an exact position on another one, (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

My goal is to insert `array B[]` into `array A[]` after the element with `index K`.

I don't need to lengthen the `A[]`, the last 5 elements should just disappear.

This is what I got so far. Dont really mind the beginning of the program, thats just some extra requirements I had to do determine the arrays.

For example :

If I insert `K`as `2`, than array `A` is 
`0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 0 0 0 0 0`, and array B is `20 40 60 80 100`. 
The final array `A` should look like this:

`0 2 4 20 40 60 80 100 6 8 10 12 14 16 18`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int A[] = new int [15];
    int B[] = new int [5];
    int K, i, j;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    for (i=10; i<=14; i++) {
        A[i] = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Matīss Lavrinovičs RDBD0 171RDB075");

    System.out.print("K=");
    if (sc.hasNextInt())
        K = sc.nextInt();
    else {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        sc.close();
        return;
    }
    sc.close();
    if (K<0 || K>9) {
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
            A[i] = r.nextInt(50);
        for (j=0; j<=4; j++)
            B[j] = r.nextInt(100 - 50) + 50; }
    else 
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
            A[i] = i*K;
        for (j=0;j<=4;j++)
            B[j] = 10*(j+1)*K; 

     System.out.print("A: ");
     i = 0;
    while (i < 15) {
        System.out.print(" " +  A[i]);
        if (i==14) System.out.println();
        i = i + 1;
    }

    System.out.print("B: ");
     j = 0;
    while (j < 5) {
        System.out.print(" " +  B[j]);
        j = j + 1;
    }


    do {

    } while;
```

Comment: And what's your question? How is the code you posted related to your question? Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.arrayCopy`:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] b = new int[] { 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };
int k = 2;

System.arraycopy(a, k + 1, a, k + 1 + b.length, a.length - b.length - k - 1);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, k + 1, b.length);
```

What happens is that we first copy the values after index #2 `b.length` places to the right (which is five). Then we copy the values of `b` into array `a` at the correct positions.

**Alternative approach:**

```
List<Integer> list = asList(a).subList(0, a.length - b.length);
list.addAll(k + 1, asList(b));
```

And a little helper method:

```
private static List<Integer> asList(int... ints) {
    return IntStream.of(ints)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

You should take the following into consideration:

- You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names start with a lowercase letter.
- Omitting curling brackets `{}` like that often leads to bugs in the code. You should always use them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use [System.arrayCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to copy from array `b[]` to array `a[]` from position `k`

```
    int[] a = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int[] b = new int[] { 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };

    int k = 1;
    int length = (a.length - k) > b.length ? b.length : (a.length - k);

    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, k, length);
```

Take care: In case array `b[]` does not fit in the remaining space in array `a[]` and as you said you don't want to lengthen array `a[]`, only copy until  there is space left (calculate `int length` with the ternary conditional operator).